# Linux gvim - toggle/retain insert-select mode while Shift key is pressed

Tags: gvim, visual-mode, insert-mode

I noticed using evim that when I press Shift key plus any direction key (so `<S-Up>`, `<S-Down>` etc., the editor automatically switches to insert-select mode, letting me select the text block with direction keys.

Since I think this mode is more handy than typing ESC, v, etc. each time, I tried to replicate this behavior using shortcuts with gvim, for example

```
:imap <S-Up> <Esc>:v<Up>
```

without success. No way.

How can I replicate this evim's behavior in gvim ?
Is this possible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The option which controls this behavior is `keymodel`.  In `evim`, it is set to `startsel,stopsel`.  From `:help 'keymodel`;

```
   startsel     Using a shifted special key starts selection (either
        Select mode or Visual mode, depending on "key" being
        present in 'selectmode').

   stopsel      Using a not-shifted special key stops selection.
```

Here, "special key" means arrows, end/home, pageup/down.

You can simply use `set keymodel=startsel` if you prefer not to cancel the selection when not pressing shift.

When using this option, `vim` will by default enter visual mode unlike `evim`, which enters select mode.  You can instead enter select mode in this case by using the additional option,

```
set selectmode+=key
```

Comment: @simo-zz Remember to mark the answer as "accepted" that is useful for future users reading your question :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove `:` in `:v` because you don't want to use the command `:v` which is the negation of `:g`, you want to press <kbd>v</kbd> in normal mode:

```
:imap <S-Up> <Esc>v<Up>
```

(Also you should use `inoremap` it is much better to avoid unwanted behaviors)

Comment: I already tried this also and it doesn't change the behavior.

Comment: @simo-zz I just tried it on my system and it works properly. Have you tried replacing `imap` by `inoremap`? And what happens when you press `<S-Up>` in insert mode after you set your mapping?

Comment: Alternatively, `set keymodel=startsel`, then no map is necessary

Comment: @Mass I had never seen this option before it is totally worth an answer! :)

Comment: @statox : Great ! The `set keymodel=startsel` is what I was looking for.Thanks !

Comment: @simo-zz Actually it's @ Mass who mentioned this setting I didn't know it so I will let him -or her- make it an answer

Comment: Yep sorry. Thank you @Mass and statox as well for your help.